# Connecting a laptop to a wifi network kills the connection for all other devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop, wireless-router

We live in a house where 5-10 devices can be connected at any time.

When a specific laptop connects to the network, the whole network seems to degrade to either not working, or slower than a snails pace.

We've spent a few hours trying to debug this. Here's what we learned.

- Wifi card on the laptop has a connection type of 802.11ax. Other devices are running on 802.11n.

  - Changing the connection type of said laptop to 802.11n does not do anything
- We've enabled 5GHz and 2.4GHz on the router. However when the laptop is connected to 5GHz, and the other devices to 2.4GHz, the internet still isn't working.
- We hotspotted another laptop (call it laptop B). When laptop A connects to laptop B hotspot, internet is working fine . This isn't a good solution though as laptop A and B may not be in the house at the same time.

Laptop A is a HP Envy 15 with an Intel WiFi 6 AX201 wireless card.
Our internet is mobile broadband, and the router is Huawei H122-373.

Comment: Try laptop A with another network card, to check if its own is broken in a way that monopolizes the router's bandwidth (unless throttled through a hotspot).

Comment: Does the laptop run a dhcp server or have a hard coded static IP address?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [disable Throughput Booster](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005585/wireless/legacy-intel-wireless-products.html) on the device that is booting the other devices off the network.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not post link only answers as the linked site might change, rendering your answer useless. Instead please quote the most important parts from the website and provide the link for reference only.